# Where's the bottleneck in this tvtropes.org scraper?

Tags: python, performance, csv, numpy

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import re
import sys
import os
import urllib2
import html5lib
from numpy import genfromtxt
import time

tropelist = []
numoftropes = 0
start = time.time()

#compare the tropelist to the master tropelist and return a 1 dimensional binary array
def binarizer(tropelist):
    mastertropelist = genfromtxt('mastertropelist.csv', dtype='str', delimiter=',')
    tropearray = []
    for item in mastertropelist:
        if item in tropelist:
            tropearray += [1]
        else:
            tropearray += [0]
    return tropearray

#need the redirect handler to account for links on the tropeswiki page concerning other series or creators. the link on the page contains /Main/ but the link it redirects to has /Series/  /Creator/ etc
def get_redirected_url(url):
    opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPRedirectHandler)
    request = opener.open(url)
    return request.url

#extracting the tropeName string from the url
def tropescraper(url):
    global tropelist
    global numoftropes
    try: #catch value errors that occur for <soup.findAll('a', {'class':'twikilink'})> items that don't contain a url
        #convert link to the redirect url
        link = str(get_redirected_url(url))
        if 'php/Main' in link:
            #truncate everything that is not the trope
            trope = (link[43:].split('?'))[0]
            #add it to the tropelist if trope not in tropelist cause many pages contain duplicates
            if trope not in tropelist:
                tropelist += [trope]
                print trope
                numoftropes+=1
    except ValueError: pass

def webcrawler(startingurl, imdbrating):
    #access page and initialize alternatetropeliststyle and declare global variables
    request = urllib2.Request(startingurl)
    url = urllib2.urlopen(request)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html5lib')
    #need this alternate tropeliststyle to account for pages that don't use the newer clickable "folder" system. this uses new webpages instead
    alternatetropeliststyle = []
    global tropelist
    global numoftropes

    #find everything with this name and tag. includes all of the links in the folders at the bottom
    for item in soup.findAll('a', {'class':'twikilink'}):
        #check if one of the links found contains TropesAToD, etc, an indicator the alternate tropelist style was implemented
        if not re.search("Tropes.To.",item['href']):
            tropescraper(item['href'])
        else:
            alternatetropeliststyle += [item['href']]

    #if alternate tropeslist was used open each "TropesAToD" etc link and run tropescraper on it after making it into soup
    if alternatetropeliststyle:
        for listedurl in alternatetropeliststyle:
            request = urllib2.Request(listedurl)
            url = urllib2.urlopen(request)      
            soup = BeautifulSoup(url, 'html5lib')

            for item in soup.findAll('a', {'class':'twikilink'}):
                tropescraper(item['href'])

    print "Total number of tropes found: ", numoftropes

    #dynamically name and create tropelists for works
    filename = subject + ' tropelist.csv'
    path_to_script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath("tlm.py"))  #create a new file no matter what
    newpath = path_to_script_dir + r'\\' + filename
    with open(newpath, 'wb') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        for trope in tropelist:
            writer.writerow([trope])
        f.close()

    #convert tropelist to array of 1's and 0's and put that array in an array that also contains the work title, rating (y-data), and total num of tropes found
    #put all this in a master array list to analyze with the classifier
    tropearray = binarizer(tropelist)
    with open('masterarraylist.csv', 'ab') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerow([subject,tropearray,imdbrating,numoftropes])
        f.close()

#media = raw_input('"Anime", ComicStrip","Webcomic","ComicBook","Film","VideoGame","Series","Literature","WesternAnimation"')
#subject = raw_input("Enter work you want to analyze (all one word and case matters!): ")
#imdbrating = raw_input("Please provide a rating from 1-10 for this work: ")
media = 'WesternAnimation'
subject = 'AdventureTime'
imdbrating = 90 #use 1-100 scale
webcrawler("http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/" + media +"/" + subject, imdbrating)

#automatically go through every work on tvtropes for a given medium, in this case WesternAnimation
# with open('WesternAnimation.csv', 'r') as f:
#     reader = csv.reader(f)
#     for row in reader:
#         webcrawler(row,_________)  #NEED TO AUTOMATICALLY SCRAPE RATINGS/GENRE OR SOMETHING BASED ON THE CAPITALIZED ONE WORD TITLE!
#     f.close()

end = time.time()

print "Time elapsed:", end-start
```

Comment: Likely the requests themselves. If you can do them asynchronously, then that would help, server round trips can take a while. I'd consider making parser and getter subclasses as well.

Comment: "Where's the bottleneck?": use cProfile, or some other profiling solution.

Answer (score 1):

Site scrapers are generally limited by the network. Some of your code is technically inefficient (for example `BeautifulSoup(url, 'html5lib')` - `lxml` based parsing is considerably faster) but it's highly unlikely to matter compared with the network overheads. Usually from the request to the response takes about 0.5 seconds and your PC can probably process dozens or hundreds of documents in that time.

The way to make it faster is to use multithreading, using multiple threads to fetch multiple pages in parallel will generally improve performance proportional to the number of threads (i.e. 4 threads = 4x faster) up to about 8 threads. However *you may not want to do this*, often a website will start refusing connections if you hit them with too many requests in too short a time. The naturally throttled rate of making only one request at a time is both safe and considerate. With that said - from my own experience you can normally get away with using 4 threads at once.

It's not hard to find examples of multi-threaded site-scrapers. In fact the python3 standard library even has an example in it's [conurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) module, and googling something like 'python multi threaded site scraper' should easily bring up some examples.